# React Native: how to change recent apps background title color on Android?

Tags: react-native

I would like to change the background title color in the recent apps view (when you press the Overview square button on Android) using react-native.

You can see in the image below that the Facebook app has a blue background color, but my *Bitcoin FOMO Calculator* app has the default gray color.

[image: Recent apps view]

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.Create colors.xml into android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Change the color value for your need -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

2.Modify the styles.xml inside android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

3.The result and more detail about [Android Style and Theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html):

[image: Android color theme]

Comment: best solution :)