# Change header color on overview screen. (React Native)

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using react native (Expo).

Is there a way to change the color of the header  of my app on the overview screen ?

[This is what I want to change the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcOQT.png)

I could not find any component or configuration yet. Maybe there is one  on Expo?

Comment: Although it does not like super ReactNative-ish, there is a way shown here (I did not try yet): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978530/react-native-how-to-change-recent-apps-background-title-color-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Please do refer this thread in github expo repository to change the primary color of the application in app.json 
[Link to github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4214)